# Multi-line regular expressions in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to perform a regex replace across multiple lines (let the match cross line boundaries)? I know there are many editors I can use for this, but it seems strange that this feature has been left out of Visual Studio. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `(.*\n)*?` to skip zero or more lines between your expressions.

`start(.*\n)*?end`

finds

```
start
two
three
end
```

`?` is the non-greedy operator, used to skip as few lines as possible.

If `end` is not the first word in the line, add `.*` to match the extra characters. I.e.: `start(.*\n)*?.*end` finds

```
start
two
three
four end end
```

If you only want to replace until the first `end`, add another non-greedy operator: `start(.*\n)*?.*?end`.

**Historic:** In Visual Studio 2017 (and early versions of 2019) you can also use the single line option in the Find and Replace dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> like this:

`(?s)start.*end`

For more see the version history of this answer.

Comment: this works but you want the extra question mark (before `end`) so it's not greedy. ie: `start(.*\n)*.*?end`

Comment: The greedy version matches as many characters as possible between `start` and `end`. If you want to find the very next `end` use the non-greedy version: `(?s)start.*?end`, or `start(.*\n)*?.*?end`.

Comment: Note to would-be users: doesn't work since Visual Studio 2013. See Giles Roberts' answer.

Comment: @relatively_random: Did you have trouble using `(?s)`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Does it still work for you on newer VS versions?

Comment: Yes. Just tested it with Visual Studio Community 2019 (Version 16.3.10). Maybe the `Find options` help.

Answer (score 92):

Regular expressions have changed in **Visual Studio 2013**.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.120).aspx

To match an expression over two lines the code would now be:

`StartOfExpression.*\r?\n.*EndOfExpression`

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, `</label>.*\r?\n.*<div` where `\r?\n` is the obvious carriage_return-new_line and `.*` for matching the possible tabs/spaces

Comment: I get the error "Literal '\n' is currently not supported"

Comment: @ELI7VH I can't replicate your error.  What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 27):

This works today in Visual Studio 2012:

```
fooPatternToStart.*(.*\n)+?.*barPatternToEnd
```

See how the `(.*\n)+?` part does the match across multiple lines, non-greedy.
`fooPatternToStart` is some regex pattern on your start line, while `barPatternToEnd` is your pattern to find on another line below, possibly many lines below...

Example found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/05/29/140147.aspx).

Simple and effective :)

Note: **before** VS2012, the pattern that worked was: `fooPatternToStart.(.\n)+@.*barPatternToEnd`

Comment: note visual studio 2012 uses the same regex engine for find/replace as within the code, so the above becomes:  fooPatternToStart.*(.*\n)*?.*barPatternToEnd

Comment: @Brent: granted, more recent versions of VSTO have fixed that issue.

Comment: what if I want to search for a text specifically in between start and stop? like this? : Edit: `sprintf.*(.*\n)+?.*log.*(.*\n)+?.*__func__` works to search for `log` between `sprintf` and `__func__`, thanks! Tho.. it seems to look into infinity for that.. if there only was a way to limit the amount of lines

Answer (score 19):

*Note: this answer is using the regex syntax used in Visual Studio up to and including VS 2012. In VS 2013 and later, the regex syntax has changed.*

You can include `\n` in the expression. As an example, here is a regex that I use to "clean" auto-generated SQL scripts from anything that is not a stored procedure (it will match text blocks that start with a line containing "Object: " followed by something that is not "StoredProcedure", then matching the following lines up to a line consists of the word "GO"):

```
/\*+ Object\::b:b~(StoredProcedure)(.*\n)#GO\n
```

Comment: Note: The line terminator depends on the format of the file, so only use \n for Unix style text, \r for Mac style text, or \r\n for windows style text.

Comment: Note II: make sure you don't have "Match whole word" ticked at the same time, otherwise this doesn't work!

Comment: Could you add a note saying that this answer only applies to Visual Studio 2012 and older please?

Answer (score 4):

you may need to use \r\n at the end of your expression.

Answer (score 2):

Non-greedy multi-line any character capture, Visual Studio 2013+:

```
.*?\r?\n.*?
```

Greedy version in Giles Roberts's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone coming here while searching for VS Code, I use this to match anything from `script` to anywhere with 2 newlines (newlines excluded):

```
script(.|\n)+?(?=\n\n)
```

replace `script` and `\n\n` to match everything between them.