# Catch the setter of some attributes with regex

Tags: c#, python, regex

I have a lot of class attributes defined this way:

```
public string ContreMarque
{
    get
    {
        return sContreMarque;
    }
    set
    {
        // bloc of code
    }
}
```

I want to transform the setters of thoses declarations to methods like for the example

```
partial void onContremarqueChanged(string value)
{
    // bloc of code
}
```

I have created a regex to do this job for me but It breaks when there's a public attribut with only the getter. You can check the work done in this link : https://regex101.com/r/dN3dJ8/5

Here's the regex in case the link breaks :

```
"\spublic (.+) (.+)\s+\{\s+get[\{\sa-z;\}]+set\s+\{\s+([a-z\s+=\(\);_0-9."\{\}/,!?]+)\t\t\t\}"mi
```

Comment: Show the regexe's in the question rather than linking off-site, because link can break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think regex is not the best tool for that, however if you want to do it this way, try this monster:

```
[^\n]+public\s(?P<type>.+?)\s(?P<name>.+?)\n+(?P<indent>\s+)\{\s+get\s+\{\s+(?P<get>[\sa-z;\}]+?)\s*\}(?:\s+set\s+\{\s+(?P<set>[a-z\s+=\(\);_0-9."\{\}/,!?]+?)\s+\})?(?=\n(?P=indent)\})\s+\}
```

[DEMO on your example with Python engine](https://regex101.com/r/dM1dU4/1)

BUT this work only if you keep clean indentation! Without it it will break. It puts relevant parts of match in named groups: `type`, `name`, `get`, `set`. Also it uses named group `indent` to determine level of indentation on which it should stop matching.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! Yes I've done some researches and found that people are only saying that regex is not the best tool, so what's the best tool for this kind of work? By the way, your regex is working like charm on my code, it only breaks when there's no getter but it's not a problem because 95% of my attributes are defined using both getter and setter. It also breaks when there's non alphabetical chars in the getter like for this one : return oRemise.Remise_Remise; and when there's multiplicaton or division in the setter.I solved this by adding the appropriate chars inside the brakets

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not related to C#, because you are using python regex engine, I can help with the issue itself.

In your original regex, you are saying that the get only has a return, but can have any bracket within it:

```
get[\{\sa-z;\}]+)set
```

The easiest thing to do is to mandate that bracket is only outside of the get logic:

```
get\s+\{[\sa-z;]+)\s+\}\s+set
```

PS: But do wish to use python or Find/Replace of Visual Studio?
Also, check the syntax errors of the brackets of the code within the set.

Comment: I want to use python because I think that multiline modifiers are not available in the Find/Replace tool in Visual studio or am I wrong ?

Comment: Depends of the version. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017278/multi-line-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio